# Integrating sum

Tags: integration, summation

- $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n k=\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}$

Which is equivalent of saying, $$1+2+3+4+5+\cdots+n=\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}$$
Now how do I integrate the left side of the equality and how that would look like?

Integrating the right side gives $\int \dfrac{n(n+1)}{2} \, \mathrm dn =\dfrac{1}{2}(\dfrac{n^3}{3}+\dfrac{n^2}{2})$

Which is quite similar to the sum $\dfrac{1}{2}\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n k^2=\dfrac{1}{2}(\dfrac{n^3}{3}+\dfrac{n^2}{2}+\dfrac{n}{6})$

Can someone explain these?

Comment: Where did you find this 'proof'. I would outright reject the book or notes that contains this.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: Don't be so quick to reject it. This kind of stuff comes up quite often (and rigorously) in Umbral Calculus: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umbral_calculus

Comment: Proofs involving derivatives and integrals of, say, a function of one variable will be taken as those defined in basic Calculus courses where you cannot perform these operations with respect to integer variables. So it necessary to mention that you are taking about Umbral Calculus so that there are no communication gaps.

Answer (score 1):

I'm choosing to interpret "taking the integral" as finding an anti-derivative, in the sense of indefinite integrals. So, we're looking for a function $F$ such that
$$F'(n) = 1 + 2 + \ldots + n.$$
In that sense, $\frac{n^3}{6} + \frac{n^2}{4}$ fits the bill; it's a function whose derivative agrees with the sum at integer points.

It is worth noting that we'll never get a function that agrees with the sum at non-integer points, as the sum doesn't make sense for non-integer points. Note that
$$1 + 2 + \ldots + 7.5$$
is a poorly-formed expression. The derivative of a function must be defined on an interval, including non-integer points (except if it's defined at a single point!). So, $\frac{n^3}{6} + \frac{n^2}{4} + C$ is about the best you're going to do.

Note also that, with the sum $\frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=1}^n k^2$, you are not integrating with respect to $n$. You are integrating the dummy variable $k$, which doesn't seem to have any conceptual connection with the original sum.

Answer (score 1):

This phenomenon is closely related to [Umbral Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umbral_calculus#The_19th-century_umbral_calculus) and [Faulhaber's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula) formula. Specifically, the Umbral form of Faulhaber's formula is:

$$\sum_{k=1}^nk^p=\frac{1}{p+1}\sum_{j=0}^p\binom{p+1}{j}B_jn^{p+1-j}=\frac{(B+n)^{p+1}-B^{p+1}}{p+1},$$

where $B$ is the "umbral" identification of Bernoulli polynomials, where we effectively stated that $B_j=B^j$ (there is a rigorous way of defining this, see the above links). This comes from the duality of $(x^n)'=nx^{n-1}$ and $(B_n(x))'=nB_{n-1}(x)$.

Write $k^p=(k+x)^p$ with $x=0$. Then, integrating both sides in $x$ and setting $x=0$ gives:

$$\frac{1}{p+1}\sum_{k=1}^nk^{p+1}=\frac{(B+n)^{p+2}-B^{p+2}}{(p+1)(p+2)},$$

as desired, after clearing the $p+1$ factors.